# Open a new Finder window in List mode with full name shown

Tags: finder

Is it possible to open a new **Finder** window in `List Mode` with the file name column stretched by default to always show the longest file name?

Oftentimes, I find myself having to double-click and adjust certain windows in order to properly view longer file names.

Is there any way to control and define this?

Answer (score 1):

[XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder) 
Has lots of features, including visualization of Finder and auto-adjusting column width.